# Create ZIP File Then Send to Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, compression, zip, export

I have a button in my web page that will export CSV files. There are 5 files in total. When the client clicks the button, the server will create the files, compress them into one ZIP file, then send the ZIP file to the client for download.

I have heard around the forums about `SharpZipLab` and `DotNetZip`, but I haven't explored any yet. I have also heard using `System.IO.Compression`. Which of these methods would you recommend?

I have this code to create the 5 CSV files:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        DataTable[] dtCSV =
        {
            file1BLO.SelectFile1ForCSV(),
            file2BLO.SelectFile2ForCSV(),
            file3BLO.SelectFile3ForCSV(),
            file4BLO.SelectFile4ForCSV(),
            file5BLO.SelectFile5ForCSV()
        };
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            DataTable dt = dtCSV[i];
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                string[] fields = dr.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", fields));
            }
            Response.ContentType = "application/text";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CAPRES-FILE" +
                (i + 1) + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + ".txt");
            Response.Output.Write(sb);
            Response.Flush();
            sb.Clear();
        }
        Response.End();
```

**EDIT** I'm using ASP.NET v4.0.

**EDIT 2** Apparently I have `System.IO.Compression`, which is weird because I though it is only supported in v4.5. Coincidentally, I don't have `System.IO.Packaging`.

Comment: I normally use `using System.IO.Compression;`

Comment: @Sachu How do you achieve this in my situation?

Comment: @JeanoErmiotano..normaally i wrote the file into disk and zip it with `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory() `

Comment: @Sachu If I write the file on disk, can I delete if afterwards? The file is sent anyways to the client and downloaded to their disk, not server disk.

Comment: @Sachu I just read the documentation for `System.IO.Compression`. Sadly, it's available on .NET v4.5+. I'm working on a .NET v4.0 project, unfortunately.

Comment: @JeanoErmitano..oh then go with sharpzipLab..

Comment: @Sachu Downloaded the ZIP, but I dunno what to do with it. I'm used to DLL files and just adding it to the project, but as a ZIP, I'm lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80146/discussion-between-sachu-and-jeano-ermitano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of **Sachu**, we were able to accomplish this requirement. We used `DotNetZip` over `SharpZipLib` due to its licensing issues.

In facilitate our development of this functionality, I ought to create a program flow based on my requirements:

1. Create text files
2. Add the text files to a folder
3. Compress this folder in `Zip` format
4. Send to client using `Response`
5. Delete files

#### Step 0 - Setup Project

Before we start the process, we must prepare the project. This include adding necessary folders and instantiate variables.

First we add a folder to which we will 'temporarily' add the text files. This folder will also be the one that will get compressed. I decided to create the folder in the root directory of the project with the name `CSV`.

Now we'll be using the `DotNetZip` library. You can download it [here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com). Add the library to your project references. Then add the using, which is `using Ionic.Zip;`.

Then we instantiate the variables such as the `zipFileName`, `textFileName`, etc. The names speak for themselves.

The data that I'll be using for the text files will be from the `DataTable[]` array, which each `DataTable` corresponding to a specific SQL query.

```
DataTable[] dtCSV =
{
    file1BLO.SelectFile1ForCSV(),
    file2BLO.SelectFile2ForCSV(),
    file3BLO.SelectFile3ForCSV(),
    file4BLO.SelectFile4ForCSV(),
    file5BLO.SelectFile5ForCSV()
};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string textFileNameTemplate = Server.MapPath(@"~\CSV") + @"\file";
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CAPRES-" + 
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + ".zip");
```

#### Step 1 - Create Text Files

This is fairly easy. I used a `StringBuilder` to convert the results from the `DataTables`. Using this, I then used a `StreamWriter` to build the text files themselves.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    DataTable dt = dtCSV[i];
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        string[] fields = dr.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", fields));
    }
    string textFileName = textFileNameTemplate + (i + 1) + ".txt";
    var textFile = new StreamWriter(textFileName);
    textFile.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    textFile.Flush();
    textFile.Close();
}
```

Notice how I used the `textFileNameTemplate` variable. I append the iterator and a `.txt` file extension. Therefore, we will have files named `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`, etc.

#### Step 3 & 4 - Compress The Folder & Send To Client

Now we can proceed with the zipping. We modified the code in Step 2 to accommodate the library.

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()) //encapsulate Step 2 code in this code block
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        DataTable dt = dtCSV[i];
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string[] fields = dr.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", fields));
        }
        string textFileName = textFileNameTemplate + (i + 1) + ".txt";
        var textFile = new StreamWriter(textFileName);
        textFile.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        textFile.Flush();
        textFile.Close();
        sb.Clear();
        zip.AddFile(textFileName, @"\"); //this is new
    }
    zip.Save(Response.OutputStream); //this is also new
}
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

`zip.AddFile(textFileName, @"\");` adds the text file to an archive. The `@"\"` means that `DotNetZip` will not create subfolders that lead to the file, e.g. if my file is in this path: `C:\User\Documents\...\file1.txt`, the archive would have a similar structure of folders. With `@"\"`, the archive will only contain the text file.

Also take note of `sb.Clear();` and its position in the code. It's important that it is inside the for loop but after the `textFile.WriteLine(sb.ToString());` line. This makes sure that strings written before are cleared before looping again. This avoid carrying over strings from `File1` to `File2`, and `File2` to `File3`, and so on.

`zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);` will directly output the Zip file to the `Response` and does not save the file in the server.

#### Step 5 - Delete Files

This step depends on your requirements. For me, we will delete the generated files. Using `System.IO.File`, we will delete the text files. After the `using ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())` code block, we'll add the following lines:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    File.Delete(textFileNameTemplate + i + ".txt");
}
```

My code probably isn't the most optimized code. But it works. If anyone can suggest a better code that would be great. But for now, I'll be using this code. Many thanks! Especially to **Sachu**, a really helpful person.